# Active Navigation Bar with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to make an active navigation bar using PHP where the current page will be highlighted or colored in the navigation bar. The code I used:

```
<ul class="topmenu">
  <li <?php if($_GET['page']="home") { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
    <a href="home.php"><b>Bienvenue</b></a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if($_GET['page']="livres") { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
    <a href="livres.php"><b>Livres</b></a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if($_GET['page']="bibliotheque") { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
    <a href="bibliotheque.php"><b>Bibliothèque</b></a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if($_GET['page']="universite") { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
    <a href="universite.php"><b>L'université</b></a>
  </li>
  <li <?php if($_GET['page']="contact") { ?> class="active" <?php } ?>>
    <a href=""><b>Contact</b></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The code will put the attribut in the class active if the page is the current page in the navigation bar. However, all the attributs will be given the class active in this case. How do I fix this?

**P.S: I am not looking for any JS or jQuery alternatives, I'm trying to make this work with PHP only.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'].

```
<ul class="topmenu">
            <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/home.php") { ?>  class="active"   <?php   }  ?>><a href="home.php"><b>Bienvenue</b></a></li>
            <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/livres.php") { ?>  class="active"   <?php   }  ?>><a href="livres.php"><b>Livres</b></a></li>
            <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/bibliotheque.php") { ?>  class="active"   <?php   }  ?>><a href="bibliotheque.php"><b>Bibliothèque</b></a></li>
            <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/universite.php") { ?>  class="active"   <?php   }  ?>><a href="universite.php"><b>L'université</b></a></li>
            <li <?php if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']=="/contact.php") { ?>  class="active"   <?php   }  ?>><a href="contact.php"><b>Contact</b></a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Same problem, I also tried using $_SERVER['CURRENT_URI']. But it always gives all the attributs the class. Logically the code should work, but knowing it doesn't is the real struggle.

Comment: Ah! Figured it out. It's because we are stupid. We were checking if the script name can be set as 'whatever.php', not if it is 'whatever.php'. == vs =

Comment: You are genius sir. It wokred as it was intended.

Comment: I've also noticed that I have to add  `if($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']="/pagename.php")` at the very top of the page in order for it to work.

Comment: I've also noticed that I must use one = in the page I'm currently at. If I use == in all the attributs it won't work.

Comment: Can you show a little bit more of your code to see what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare page variables at the very top of each individual page.
2. Example: `<? $page="home";?>`
3. For each list item in your nav bar add if statment with corresponding variable and active class.
4. Example:  `<li class="<?if($page=="home"){?>active<?}?>"><a href="home.php"><b>Bienvenue</b></a></li>`

What this does is assign each page a variable.  The variable is compared in the if statements in the nav bar to determine which li gets the active class.

Comment: If I do this method, doesn't it mean in each if of every page will return true? Since the variable will be assigned with "home" and it is true for every if. Am I understanding you wrong?

Comment: It's only going to return true in the li where the page variable you've assigned matches in the if statements.  
If you are on the livres page, at the top of your php you will write in `<? $page="livres";?>`.   On the bibliotheque page, `<? $page="bibliotheque";?>` should be at the top.
Your navbar should be
 `<ul> 
<li class="<?if($page=="home"){?>active<?}?>"><a href="home.php"><b>Bienvenue</b></a></li>
<li class="<?if($page=="livres"){?>active<?}?>"><a href="livres.php"><b>livres</b></a></li>
<li class="<?if($page=="bibliotheque"){?>active<?}?>"></li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't use PHP, but give the current page the active tag, and change it per file. Then a single class definition in the CSS handles changing the color for each page.

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <a class="active" href="/home/">Home</a>
    <a href="/cal/">Calendar</a>
    <a href="/CC/">Community</a>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

Comment: That's a way to do it I agree, but I'm trying to make this PHP way work as it's automatic and doesn't requires creating too many classes.

Comment: Fair enough, figured I would suggest it since it still lets it be managed by a single class in CSS. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bootstrap 4 class. I've achieved Active Class selection something like this.

```
<li class="nav-item">
    <a 
    <?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/somepath/yourfile1.php") { ?> 
         class="nav-link active" 
    <?php   } else {  ?>
         class="nav-link"
    <?php } ?> 
         href="yourfile1.php">Home
    </a>
 </li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a 
    <?php if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] == "/somepath/yourfile2.php") { ?> 
         class="nav-link active" 
    <?php   } else {  ?>
         class="nav-link"
    <?php } ?> 
         href="yourfile2.php">Home
    </a>
 </li>
```

Repeat this logic for further li tags. Hope this helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

The code work correctly if you use "==" instead of "=" in The if construct

Еxample:

```
 if($_GET['page'] **==** "home")...
```

Instead:

```
if($_GET['page'] **=** "home")...
```

Hope this helps someone else...